# The sum of two columns and only show the third column

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to write and execute the SQL query that returns the top three records with the highest "score", where the "score" is the sum of two columns (let's call them X and Y).  The result should have one column named score.

Here is what I did

```
%%sql
select X,Y,(X + Y) as score from survey
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 3
```

I got the right answer but I only want the score column, not the x and y column too.
`Done. X   Y   score 4   9   13 4   8   12 3   7   10`

Comment: so do not `select` `x` and `y`. `select (X + Y) as score from survey ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT X, Y, (X+Y) ...
```

gives the 3 columns since you have SELECT 3 things. Instead just SELECT what you need in your case,

```
SELECT (X + Y) as score from survey
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 3
```